# Passing socket to thread instead of fd?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

Im using this function to accept a new client and pass it to a thread

```
struct sockaddr_in client;
while(1) {
    len = sizeof(client);
    fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &len);
    if(fd>0) {
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, process_thread, (LPVOID)fd, 0, &thread);
        // pthread_create( &thread , NULL , process_thread , (int)fd);
    }
}
```

and handle it like

```
DWORD WINAPI process_thread(LPVOID lpParam) {
//void process_thread(int sock) {
    SOCKET fd = (SOCKET)lpParam;
    //int fd = sock;
    ....  
}
```

Can i also create a new thread with the `client` structure (sockaddr_in) and pick the fd inside the handler function like

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, process_thread, (SOCKET)client, 0, &thread);
```

and how? And if so how to accept after creating the thread? Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: `client` isn't a socket so I don't know what "the `client` socket" means.

Comment: i have edited the question its a `struct sockaddr_in`, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is create a new struct to hold both your values:

```
struct process_thread_info
{
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    SOCKET fd;
};
```

and then you can pass this structure:

```
// We must use malloc to create a new struct for every client.
// We can't just declare one here and then use its address,
// because it might go out of scope before the process_thread receives the info.
struct process_thread_info *threadinfo = malloc(sizeof(struct process_thread_info));
threadinfo->fd = fd;
threadinfo->client = client;

CreateThread(NULL, 0, process_thread, threadinfo, 0, &thread);
// pthread_create( &thread , NULL , process_thread , threadinfo);
```

As with any other usage of `malloc`, don't forget to have the thread `free` the struct when it's finished using it.

Comment: Thats great with a struct, i already know of it but havent thought about that and that i can pass it to a thread, thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry but how does the `process_thread()` function would look like?

Comment: @Rajana `struct process_thread_info *info = (struct process_thread_info*)lpParam;`

Comment: And lpParam (the parameter to process_thread) is of type process_thread_info? And whats the return type of the function?

Comment: Maybe a function definition without a lot of code would be nice.

Comment: @Rajana `struct process_thread_info *threadinfo = malloc(sizeof(struct process_thread_info)); ... if (!CreateThread(..., threadinfo, ...)) free(threadinfo); ...  DWORD WINAPI process_thread(LPVOID lpParam) { struct process_thread_info *threadinfo = (struct process_thread_info *) lParam; ... free(threadinfo); return 0; }`